# Delta Indexing Only Working in Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I'm running sphinx, thinking sphinx on our rails3 application. I'm also using passenger on osx 10.6.

Everything's fine but I simply cannot get my delta indexes to work when I create a record in a browser.

In the console, I get the following output and my record's displayed in the view:

```
Sphinx 2.0.2-dev (r2875)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/Users/jennyb/railsprojects/orders/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'company_delta'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 14336 kb
collected 2 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 2 docs, 30 bytes
total 0.009 sec, 3291 bytes/sec, 219.44 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=48890).
=> #<Company id: 26, name: "Bobs Your Uncle", number: "123456", address: "204 Some Studio", town: "London", postcode: "W1", phone: "0207123456", createdby: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-07-18 08:24:26", updated_at: "2011-07-18 08:24:26", notes: nil, vip: nil, delta: true>
```

I've been through the documentation, rebuilt my indexes etc. The only thing I can assume is that it's a permissions problem. The docs say searchd has to be run as same user as www.

Apache2 is running as www user on my mac. I can't see why I should change this to run as ts user?

-- UPDATE --

Sphinx.rb:

```
development:
  min_infix_len: 3
  bin_path: "/usr/local/bin"
  version: 2.0.5
  mem_limit: 128M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I found an error appearing when adding a company through the browser...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/indexer
  Reason: image not found
```

To solve this mysql load issue, I followed the [following suggestion](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/) and ran this:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/bin/indexer

sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/bin/search
```

Now, creating a record in the browser, I can see my delta indexing working again. woohoo!

Hope this helps someone out there...

Answer (score 0):

mem_limit setup as 0 can't be used. can you tune your thinking_sphinx configuration with according to [official documentation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html)?

development:
  mem_limit: 128M

Comment: Hello @mikhailov, the memory limit doesn't seem to have any impact on the fact that delta indexing is only working in the console...

Comment: Hi - have added to initial question. Sorry for not including.

Comment: did you try the stable Sphinx release?

Comment: tried with 2.0.3 as per documentation as I'm on Rails3. Still not working :(

Comment: did you install thinking_sphinx rails3 branch?